# Regex and adding HTML tags wrap and formatting

Tags: css, regex, html, regex-lookarounds

I'm currently trying to format a text document into an html document (with divs and containers) and I was wondering if Regex find and replace is actually the way to go, I've only partly got the solution however I am unable to get how to wrap each main item in a container.

Data:

```
Name: Person1
Address: Add1.
Office hours: 8:30 AM - 6:00 PM Mon - Sat <br> 9:30 AM - 3:00 PM Sun

Name: Person2
Address: Add2
Office hours: Not Available

Name: Person3
Address: Add3
Office hours: 8:30 AM - 6:00 PM Mon - Sun
```

I was able to get the part of wrapping each row, but I wasn't able to get the part of wrapping each group in a container via code below.

Using **Regexr** and **regex101**

RegEx Find: `([A-Za-z]+.?[A-Za-z]+)(?:\:)(.+)`

Replace result: `<div class="datarow"><label>\1</label><div class="value">\:\2</div></div>`

```html
<div class="datarow">
    <label>Name</label>
    <div class="value"> Person1</div>
</div>
<div class="datarow">
    <label>Address</label>
    <div class="value"> Add1.</div>
</div>
<div class="datarow">
    <label>Office hours</label>
    <div class="value"> 8:30 AM - 6:00 PM Mon - Sat <br> 9:30 AM - 3:00 PM Sun </div>
</div>



<div class="datarow">
    <label>Name</label>
    <div class="value"> Person2</div>
</div>
<div class="datarow">
    <label>Address</label>
    <div class="value"> Add2</div>
</div>
<div class="datarow">
    <label>Office hours</label>
    <div class="value"> Not Available</div>
</div>

...
```

**Would've wanted this Output:**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="datarow">
        <label>Name</label>
        <div class="value"> Person1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="datarow">
        <label>Address</label>
        <div class="value"> Add1.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="datarow">
        <label>Office hours</label>
        <div class="value"> 8:30 AM - 6:00 PM Mon - Sat <br> 9:30 AM - 3:00 PM Sun </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="datarow">
        <label>Name</label>
        <div class="value"> Person2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="datarow">
        <label>Address</label>
        <div class="value"> Add2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="datarow">
        <label>Office hours</label>
        <div class="value"> Not Available</div>
    </div>
</div>

...
```

I am not sure if RegEx is truly the way to go, but I'd really like to use it since there are like a thousand people, address, and office hours which I need to format as HTML above. Is it at all possible to achieve my desired output? or is there a better way to do it? Suggestions, especially explanations, would highly be appreciated since I really am in a pickle. :(

Edit:
Using pcre-php language which is default for regex101

Comment: Will prolly sleep in a few, might be having a nightmare with this :(

Comment: which language are you using and if you tried something please edit the post with the things you tried?

Comment: Hi @aa-Ahmed-aa I did reflect the things Ive tried and where i tried in the post. I dont know why I got the down vote. Legitimate question and looking for advise.

Comment: I have changed the flow **from** Stating problem > Stating Given > Stating Desired Results > Approaches tested **to** Stating problem > Stating Given > Approaches tested  > Stating Desired Results

Comment: you get the down votes because you didn't mention your tries and you didn't mention the language you are using for this task ?
you can use regex but in which language?

Comment: I did mention the things ive tried upon posting this question. It was after the desired output. I have even mentioned the flow in my previous comment. I always try to provide every info i have includinf the desired output because many people whove answered my questions before have asked that of me. Adding language (pcre-php) default of regex101

Answer (score 0):

So you need to walkthrough these steps make your task

- Extract your data and store them in array
- Loop throw the data and output the array you get

**data.txt**

```
Name: Person1
Address: Add1.
Office hours: 8:30 AM - 6:00 PM Mon - Sat <br> 9:30 AM - 3:00 PM Sun

Name: Person2
Address: Add2
Office hours: Not Available

Name: Person3
Address: Add3
Office hours: 8:30 AM - 6:00 PM Mon - Sun
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents('data.txt');

    //extract names from the content
    $re = '/Name: ([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/';
    $names = extractFromContent($re, $content);

    //extract addresses 
    $re = '/Address: ([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/';
    $addresses = extractFromContent($re, $content); 

    //extract office hours
    $re = "/Office hours: ([A-Za-z0-9:\-<>,;' ]*)/";
    $office_hours = extractFromContent($re, $content);

    // var_dump($names);
    // var_dump($addresses);
    // var_dump($office_hours);

    $max = max( count($names),count($addresses), count($office_hours) );


    function extractFromContent($regex, $content)
    {   
        preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
        $extracted = [];
        foreach($matches as $index => $match)
        {
            $extracted[] = $matches[$index][1];
        }

        return $extracted;
    }

    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title of page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="content">
        
    </div>
    <?php for( $i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++ ): ?>
        <div class="datarow">
            <label>Name</label>
            <div><?= $names[$i] ?></div>
        </div>  
        <div class="datarow">
            <label>Address</label>
            <div><?= $addresses[$i] ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="datarow">
            <label>Office hours</label>
            <div><?= $office_hours[$i] ?></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    <?php endfor; ?>

</body>
</html>
```